# Python multiple comparisons evaluation order

Tags: python, python-3.x, operator-precedence, evaluation, comparison-operators

I don't see why the following expression evaluates to `False`:

```python
>>> 1 in [1,2,3] == True
False
```

`in` and `==` has the same precedence and groups left to right, but:

```python
>>> (1 in [1,2,3]) == True
True
```

and

```python
>>> 1 in ([1,2,3] == True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable
```

Where is the problem with the parenthesis?

Comment: It is call a comparison operators chain and evaluated as `(1 in [1,2,3]) and ([1,2,3] == True)`.

Comment: @KlausD. Thank you very much!

Comment: See [Operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) in documentation (and the [Evaluation order](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order) section right above it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparison operators at the same level "chain".  You may have seen something such as `10 < x < 25`, which expands to `(10 < x) and (x < 25)`.

Similarly, your original expression expands to

```
(1 in [1,2,3]) and ([1,2,3] == True)
```

The first expression evaluates as `True`, as you already know.  The second expression returns `False`, giving the result you see.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I see, but... are you sure `[1,2,3] == True` throws a run-time error? Isn't it a legitimate expression that evaluates to `False`?

Comment: `[1,2,3] == True` does return `False`

Comment: Yes, it does -- I had different punctuation when I elicited that run-time error.
I've fixed my answer.